# 3D Tensor in a correct data shape for neural network

Tags: pandas, dataframe, neural-network, keras, jupyter-notebook

I'm starting with Neural Networks and I'm having some issues with my data format. I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` with `130` rows, `4` columns and each data point is an array of `595` items.

```
      |      Col 1      |    Col 2        |    Col 3        |    Col 4        |
Row 1 | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] |
Row 2 | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] |
Row 3 | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] | [x1, ..., x595] |
```

I created the *X_train*, *X_test*, *y_train* and *y_test* using *train_test_split*. However, when I check the shape of *X_train* it returns (52,4) and I'm not being able to create a model for my NN because it doesn't accept this shape. This is the error:

> "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_4_input to have
>   3 dimensions, but got array with shape (52, 4)"

I believe it's because it should be `(52,4,595)`, right? So, I'm kind of confused, how can I specify this *input_format* correctly or maybe reshape my data for the appropriate data format?

I am using `pandas`, `keras`, `tensorflow` and `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Please add the code of your model as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras error: expected dense\_input\_1 to have 3 dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233169/keras-error-expected-dense-input-1-to-have-3-dimensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reshape your data to a 3d numpy array.

Suppose we have a data frame where each cell is a numpy array as you described

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((130,4))).astype('object')
for i in range(130):
    for k in range(4):
        #print(i,k)
        data.iloc[i,k]=np.zeros(595)
```

we can then reshape our data frame to a 3d numpy array doing:

```
dataar=data.values
dataar=np.stack((np.vstack(dataar[:,0]),np.vstack(dataar[:,1]),np.vstack(dataar[:,2]),np.vstack(dataar[:,3])))
dataar=dataar.reshape(130,4,595)
dataar.shape
# (130, 4, 595)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I try to reshape I get: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 520 into shape (130,4,595).

Comment: if not all data points are of equal length, a solution would be to either pad sequences with a value or use minimum length for every point.

Comment: but they are. All of them have len of 595. :(

Comment: did you tried my code above for reshaping your data?

Comment: Yes, I get an error when trying to stack (ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly).

Comment: this error means that not all data points are of the same length (595)

Comment: I tested for dataar[:,0].shape, dataar[:,1].shape, dataar[:,2].shape and dataar[:,3].shape. They all have the same shape.

Comment: you will have to check the length of all data points.
for row in data.shape[0]:
    for col in data.shape[1]:
       print(len(data.iloc[row,col]))

Comment: Amazing. haha... Used a for loop to print all indexes different from 595 and found one last annoying datapoint with 594! Unbelievable! Now, it works like a charm. Thank you for your help and patience. :)

Comment: glad i could helped